# Replace special characters and spaces with empty string with REGEX

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, webforms

I am looking to take a string from an input text box and remove all special characters and spaces.

e.g.
Input: ##HH 4444 5656 3333 2AB##
Output: HH4444565633332AB

Comment: what have you already tried ?

Comment: `string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\W+", "");` - we replace all non-word chars (which are not letters or digits) with empty string

Comment: What precisely is it that you vaguely describe as "special characters"?

Comment: So I wanted to try Regex but have never used it before, this is all very new to me. I wanted to essentially only remove spaces and #, however I want to account for everything that isn't a digit or a letter to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dealing with [unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to remove [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) characters that [is not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a letter nor a number:

```
[^\p{L}\p{N}]+
```

[See this demo at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5D%2B&i=%23%23HH%204444%205656%203333%202AB%23%23&r=) or a [C# replace demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##fU9NSwMxEL3nVwzZSxfrFtT2sgh@IFSoIn7gwVYIcVgD22TJZGWl7G9fx0RrRfAdQt68NzNvNO1r53EYWjK2grt3CrguxS4r7rELxS1Wba38Rdd4JDLOUimErhUR3HhXebUWGwEMCioYDW/OvMCVMnaUx3ISPzGZwKVt2sBOz1uKrZA4mCgeg8yy@RyOGDCdTWdwyICD07Msk@W255yDuBqLR28CLozFUWzPfxy7ex8IgQ/Bjs9paqURggP//X1FaFQI6C1niDTO@hPQtSEl/DUqLR7DiXx6XjabRc/Pdb/ak2OQMv8vcZr3ZelFPwwf)

- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `\p{N}` matches any kind of numeric character in any script

Answer (score 1):

Let's define what we are going to *keep*, not what to *remove*. If we keep Latin letters and digits only we can put

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
```

or (Linq alternative)

```
string result = string.Concat(input
  .Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' c >= '0' && c <= '9'));
```